# NameError: name 'args' is not defined when trying to print out the number of vowels in a string

Tags: python

Create a program called countVowels.py that has a function that takes in a string then prints the number of unique vowels in the string (regardless of it being upper or lower case).

**countVowels.py**

```
import sys

def count_vowels(args):
    vowels = set()

    for arg in args:
        for char in arg:
            if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
                vowels.add(char)
    return len(vowels)

print(count_vowels(sys.argv[1:]))
```

**Test Cases**

```
python3 countVowels.py Data
python3 countVowels.py 'Python Python'
python3 countVowels.py 'eiOuayOI j_#Ra'
```

**The following is the error message displayed:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "countVowels.py", line 14, in <module>
    count_vowels(args)
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Comment: what would be the best text editor to run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, because it's not defined.  You need to pass the sys.argv subset to the function.  Right now, you are throwing away the parameter `args` by overwriting it.

What you should do is delete the `sys.argv` reference in the function:

```
def count_vowels(args):
    count = 0 
...
```

And change the main to:

```
count_vowels(sys.argv[1:])
```

### Followup

To get the number of UNIQUE vowels, you should collect them all into a set, then count the length of the set.

```
def count_vowels(args):
    vowels = set() 
    for arg in args:
        for char in arg:
            if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
                vowels.add(char)
    return len(vowels)

print(count_vowels(args))
```

Comment: Don't edit your question *after* it has been answered. If you have further issues, post a new question.